# how to clear validation errors for mat error after submitting the form

Tags: angular, angular-material

i am not able to clear validation errors for mat error after submitting the form. i am reseting the form by form.resetForm() after submitting but still i am not able to clear validations of the mat error.i tried reintializing the form too.can you please help?. Thanks inAdvance.

Here is the [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pchzpw)

Comment: Are you using `ngForm` ?

Comment: i tried using ngForm but still i can't able to clear validations @Mridul

Comment: Provide the stackblitz edit url.

Comment: Provided @Mridul

Comment: Check and make changes accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don´t need `ngForm`. You can simple set the errors of your control to `null`.

```
onSubmitchngPwd() {
    this.changepwdform.get("currentpassword").setErrors(null);  // set errors to null
}
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-en6coj

Comment: Its working perfectly for me. Thank you very much. @JuNe

Answer (score 2):

Take reference from here using `ngForm`

`In your Html file`

```
<form  fxFlex fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" [formGroup]="noteForm" #noteForm="ngForm">
```

`In your ts file`

```
 @ViewChild('noteForm', { static: true }) noteForm: NgForm;
//to reset form
this.noteForm.resetForm();
```

Replace names accordingly in your HTML and TS files.

Comment: Thanks but its not working. validation errors are getting cleared but the form is not getting cleared completely and i am getting the validation error in the console.

Comment: Seems like the problem is in your `validationService`. please check that

Comment: JuNe's answer worked for me.Thanks for spending your time in helping me :) @Mridul

Answer (score 0):

In the material design the **mat-errors** get fires when the control is touched or dirty so we need to mark them as untouched the controls after resetting the forms following is the code for making the control untouched:

> this.pwdform.controls.newpassword.markAsUntouched();
>   this.pwdform.controls.currentpassword.markAsUntouched();
>   this.pwdform.controls.confirmpassword.markAsUntouched();